# Background color when hovering datagrid row

Tags: tables, color, data-tables, hover

My question is pretty simple. In your opinion, does changing the background color of the hovered row in the datagrid is a plus for the user - or a distraction that should be discarded? All rows / columns are already separated by a dotted line.

Comment: This probably requires a screenshot of some kind because the type of visual styling applied would make a difference to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You will get better idea from below article

[Design Better Data Tables](https://uxdesign.cc/design-better-data-tables-4ecc99d23356)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question depends on how the styling of the data grid has been implemented. For example, the usual zebra-striping applied to tables and data grids actually reduce the impact of highlighting because there are already alternate colour patterns, so you should provide an outline of the cell/row instead. However, if you applied good whitespacing in the design, it allows you to use background colour change on hover-over to create a stronger visual impact. But there are different views on this and I think you can find other answers like this: [Hover states on tables with striping](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/55533/hover-states-on-tables-with-striping)

It is also important to consider the context of such as designing for mobile devices versus desktop devices, as you might want to think about how a user will know their place in a data grid without the highlight.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely a plus, as this is a pretty common functionality (implemented by enterprise DataGrid components like [Shield UI's](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/basic-usage)), especially if the datagrid supports some kind of interaction like selection, clicks, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[image: DataGrid Design]

--> [Animated version](https://dribbble.com/shots/1903644-Data-Grid)

Here is a excellent shot designed by Virgil Pana using a lot of features described in the Design Better Data Table article.

Comment: The contrast between the text and table cell shading could be a little bit better, but it does look very clean and well laid out.

Answer (score 2):

IF the datagrid is very dense (meaning - high number of column/rows/ and small font) and IF  each row spans the entire width of the screen then it is helpful to add a hover background color. Librarians/accountants in olden days would use a wooden ruler to scan across rows in their big ledger books.

Comment: That is true, the issue being that my grids are fully dynamic - knowing it is impossible to know what will be inside before runtime :) Not to mention that the layout is fluid so the grid can be displayed on any screen size.